# Can anyone assist me with optiising my query to reduce result time?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have written a MYSQL query without much expertise in this area but as my database has increased in size, I'm finding the results are taking far too long to be returned. I can understand why but I can't figure out how to better group my query so that MYSQL isn't searching through the entire database to return the results. I know there is a far more efficient way to do this but I can't figure out how. If I remove the ORDER BY statement, the results are returned in less than a quarter of the time. As it stands now with a table that has 180,000 entries in it (members), it's taking about 4 seconds to return the results.

```
SELECT members.mem_id, members.username, members.online, 
       members.dob, members.regdate, members.sex, 
       members.mem_type, members.aboutme, 
       geo_cities.name AS city, 
       geo_countries.name AS country, photos.photo_path
        FROM members
        LEFT JOIN geo_cities
        ON members.cty_id=geo_cities.cty_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN geo_countries
        ON geo_cities.con_id=geo_countries.con_id
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN photos
        ON members.mem_id=photos.mem_id
        WHERE (photos.main=1 
          AND photos.approved=1
          AND members.banned!="1"
          AND members.profile_photo="1"
          AND members.profile_essentials="1"
          AND members.profile_user="1")
        ORDER BY lastdate DESC
        LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Optimizing JOIN's with ORDER BY can be tricky.. Ideally MySQL should acces the table first with the `lastdate` column to avoid needing a temporary memory handling. "using temporary" in the explain which can be ram memory based or a disk based temporary depending how much data MySQL allows in the ram memory temporary  table which is configured..

Comment: Questions about performance should include table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>`) structures for every table involved in the SQL query and also a `EXPLAIN <query>`

Comment: What @RaymondNijland said.  Read this, especially the section on query performance, and then please [edit] your question.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: What table is `lastdate` in???  It makes a _big_ difference in optimizing!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to show the most recent 12 members who meet certain criteria.

A few things.

1. Your `RIGHT JOIN` on `photos` is actually an ordinary inner `JOIN`: its columns appear in your `WHERE` clause.
2. You probably need compound indexes on the `members` and `photos` tables.
3. `SELECT many columns FROM ... JOIN ... ORDER BY column... LIMIT 12` is a notorious performance antipattern: It constructs a complex result set, then sorts the whole thing, then discards almost all of it. Wasteful.
4. You have `WHERE....members.banned != "1"` Inequality filters like this make SQL work harder (==slower) than equalities. If you can change that to `= "0"` or something like that do it.

(I guess your `lastdate` column is in your `members` table, but you didn't tell us that in your question.)

So try something like this to find the twelve members you want to display.

```
          SELECT members.mem_id
            FROM members
            JOIN photos ON members.mem_id=photos.mem_id
           WHERE photos.main=1 
             AND photos.approved=1
             AND members.banned!="1"
             AND members.profile_photo="1"
             AND members.profile_essentials="1"
             AND members.profile_user="1")
           ORDER BY lastdate DESC
           LIMIT 12
```

That gets you the ids of the twelve members you want. Use it in your main query.

```
    SELECT members.mem_id, members.username, members.online, 
           members.dob, members.regdate, members.sex, 
           members.mem_type, members.aboutme, 
           geo_cities.name AS city, 
           geo_countries.name AS country, photos.photo_path
      FROM members
      LEFT JOIN geo_cities    ON members.cty_id=geo_cities.cty_id
      LEFT JOIN geo_countries ON geo_cities.con_id=geo_countries.con_id
      JOIN photos ON members.mem_id=photos.mem_id
    WHERE members.mem_id IN (
          SELECT members.mem_id
            FROM members
            JOIN photos ON members.mem_id=photos.mem_id
           WHERE photos.main=1 
             AND photos.approved=1
             AND members.banned!="1"
             AND members.profile_photo="1"
             AND members.profile_essentials="1"
             AND members.profile_user="1")
           ORDER BY lastdate DESC
           LIMIT 12
         )
    ORDER BY lastdate DESC
    LIMIT 12
```

This finds the twelve members you care about, then pulls out only their records, instead of pulling all the records.

Then, create a compound index on `members(profile_photo, profile_essentials, profile_user, banned, lastdate)`. That compound index will speed up your `WHERE` clause a great deal.

Likewise, create a compound index on `photos(mem_id, main, approved, photo_path)`.

Things always get exciting when databases start to grow!  Read Markus Winand's online book https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: This _assumes_ that `lastdate` is in `members`.

Comment: May as well tack on `photo_path` to the secind index, making it "covering".

Comment: Thanks. That's guys, that's been really helpful :)